# Casting from member pointer to whole struct/class

Tags: c++, function, struct, casting, callback

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>


struct bar {
  double a = 1.0;
  int b = 2;
  float c = 3.0;
};

void callbackFunction(int* i) {

  auto myStruct = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i) - offsetof(bar, b);

  std::cout << myStruct->a << std::endl;
  std::cout << myStruct->b << std::endl;
  std::cout << myStruct->c << std::endl;

  //do stuff
}

int main() {

  bar foo;

  callbackFunction(&foo.b);

  return 0;
}
```

I have to define a callback function and I want to use some additional information in that function. I defined my own struct and pass the address of a member to the function. In the function I want to "retrieve" the whole struct by casting, but the pointers don't seem to match and I get wrong results. I guess I'm doing something wrong while casting but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a cast to make this work. You need to cast to a byte type before subtracting the offset, and then recast back to `bar*`. The reason is that the macro `offsetof` returns the offset as a number of bytes. When you do pointer arithmetic, subtraction and addition work in terms of the size of the pointed type. Let's make an example:

Let's assume that you have a `bar` instance, named `b` that is at address 0x100h. Assuming that `sizeof(double) == 8`, `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(float) == 4`, then `sizeof(bar) == 16` and your struct and its members would look like that in memory:

```
b @ 0x100h
b.a @ 0x100h
b.b @ 0x108h
b.c @ 0x10Ch
```

`offsetof(bar,b)` would be equal to `8`. Your original code says 'treat 0x108h as if it's pointing to a struct of type `bar`. then give me the `bar` struct at address `0x108h - 8 * sizeof(bar)`, or specifically: 0x108h - 0x80h = 88h.' Hopefully the example demonstrates why the original code was performing the wrong calculation.

This is why you need to tell the compiler that you want to subtract the addresses as bytes instead, to get to the correct address of the first member in your struct.

The solution would look something like this:

`bar* owner = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(reinterpret_cast<char *>(i) - offsetof(bar, b));`

One thing that you should be very careful about: This is legit *only if* `bar` is **standard layout**. You can use the template `std::is_standard_layout<bar>::value` to make a static assert to verify you're not accidentally invoking UB.

Comment: Thanks, for you thorough explanation.

Comment: I guess I still need to read about pointer arithmetic :D But now I understand the problem.

Comment: The intuitive way to think about it (for me) is that pointer arithmetic does the right thing in the common case:

if you have an `int* a` then `a + 1` will get you the next int in memory, after the first one is 'over', so to say. if you have a `double* a`, then `a + 1` will give you the next double in memory. If you have a `HugeStruct1KB* hugeStruct`, `hugeStruct +1` would give you the next such struct - which is at an offset that is intuitively different than the offset for a simple integer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with `reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i)` you basically treat `i` as a pointer to the first element of an array of `bar` structures.

This is problematic because for any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`.

So the whole expression `reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i) - offsetof(bar, b)` is basically similar to `&(reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i))[-offsetof(bar, b)]`. That is, you get a pointer to element `-offsetof(bar, b)` in this "array". This is of course not a correct index.

It would work if you had an "array" of *bytes* instead of the "array" of `bar` structures:

```
char* tempPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(i) - offsetof(bar, b);
bar* myStructPtr = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(tempPtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're moving your pointer back by too much, the offsetof `b` is `sizeof(double)`, so probably 8, but the expression `reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i) - offsetof(bar, b)` moves it by `sizeof(bar) * sizeof(double)`.

While it's technically legal to to cast a `struct/class` to it's 1st member, you should never **need** to do that, it can very easily lead to **UB**.

Answer (score 1):

If you just switch around the `int` and `double` member, so that the `int` member is first, then, because your class is standard-layout, you can simply `reinterpret_cast` to the `struct` and access the other members normally, because the first non-static data member and the class object will be [*pointer-interconvertible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible):

```
struct bar {  // Must be standard-layout!
  int b = 2;  // Must be first non-static data member!
  double a = 1.0;
  float c = 3.0;
};

void callbackFunction(int* i) {

  auto myStruct = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(i);

  std::cout << myStruct->a << std::endl;
  std::cout << myStruct->b << std::endl;
  std::cout << myStruct->c << std::endl;

  //do stuff
}


int main() {

  bar foo;

  callbackFunction(&foo.b);

  return 0;
}
```